# Disable phaselistener in production mode

Tags: jsf

I have set up few things quite useful for our app. Useful in development mode, but not in production. For exemple, I registered this phaselistener

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>org.primefaces.component.lifecycle.LifecyclePhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

In production mode, there is no need to have this, so I was wondering how you guys with JSF app are you disabling things by taking account the PROJECT_STAGE state in production mode?

PS: In xhtml pages, I'm aware it is easy as I can decide to not render component by using `#{facesContext.application.projectStage eq 'Development'}`

Answer (score 2):

You can register the PhaseListener programatically instead of via faces-config.xml, for example:

```
@ManagedBean(eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationBean {

    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() {
        LifecycleFactory factory = (LifecycleFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.LIFECYCLE_FACTORY);
        Lifecycle lifecycle = factory.getLifecycle(LifecycleFactory.DEFAULT_LIFECYCLE);
        if (ProjectStage.Development.equals(getProjectStage())) {
            lifecycle.addPhaseListener(new PhaseListenerImpl());
        }
    }

    private ProjectStage getProjectStage() {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Application appl = fc.getApplication();
        return appl.getProjectStage();
    }
}
```

(cf. http://javaevangelist.blogspot.de/2012/05/jsf-2-tip-of-day-programmatic.html)

Comment: Thank for the tip! Indeed that should do the job, but I don't like the idea of playing with managed bean scope, and plus you need to use eager attribute. That makes the code quite sensitive. But thanks to your idea, 'cause I never thought about adding it programmtically. What I did is to use System Event Listener with PostConstructApplicationEvent event

Answer (score 1):

Using system event listener (See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_applicationevents_tag.htm):

```
public class PostConstructApplicationListener implements SystemEventListener {

    @Override
    public void processEvent(SystemEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof PostConstructApplicationEvent) {
            setupLifeCycleListener();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add <code>org.primefaces.component.lifecycle.LifecyclePhaseListener</code> in case PROJECT_STAGE is not set to "Production"
     */
    private void setupLifeCycleListener() {
        if (Faces.getApplication().getProjectStage() != ProjectStage.Production) {
            LifecycleFactory factory = (LifecycleFactory) FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.LIFECYCLE_FACTORY);
            Lifecycle lifecycle = factory.getLifecycle(LifecycleFactory.DEFAULT_LIFECYCLE);
            lifecycle.addPhaseListener(new LifecyclePhaseListener());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isListenerForSource(Object source) {
        return source instanceof Application;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by extending the `Primefaces LifecyclePhaseListener` and returning `null` from `getPhaseId()` method if not in development mode.

```
public class LifecycleForDevelopmentPhaseListener extends LifecyclePhaseListener {
    @Override
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        if (!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isProjectStage(ProjectStage.Development)) {
            return null;
        }
        return super.getPhaseId();
    }

}
```

This will bypass the phase listener